# Prove or disprove the following: For all rational numbers $x$ and $y$, the number $x^y$ is also rational.

Tags: discrete-mathematics, proof-writing, solution-verification

Prove or disprove: For all rational numbers $x$ and $y$, the number $x^y$ is also rational.

I think that the statement is true since I can not come up with a counterexample but I am unsure of where to go from here... If anyone can finish the proof for me that would be greatly appreciated along with any explanations!

Proof: Suppose $x$ and $y$ are rational numbers $x = p/q$ and $y = r/s$.

Is $(p/q)^{(r/s)}$ rational since it can not be expressed as the ratio of two integers?...

Thank you in advance!

Edit: Sorry for my confusion! I now understand how the square root of two makes the statement false.

Comment: What's the obvious counterexample?

Comment: No, it is false ... $\sqrt 2$ is not rational

Comment: no, $2^{1/2} = \sqrt 2$

Comment: It is obviously false. What's the first number you have heard of being asked to prove of as an irrational number? ;-)

(This question has a nice counterpart with all the "rational"-s replaced by "irrational"-s)

Comment: @Fawkes4494d3 Wow I really got rational and irrational mixed up.. sorry about that! Maybe I should not be studying discrete math but should be reviewing my old vocabulary haha

Comment: Below, I used the example of $2^{\frac{1}{TREE(3)}}$ as an counterexample.

If $2^{\frac{1}{TREE(3)}}$  were rational,. it would imply the existence of an immodular semistable elliptiuc curve (per Ken Ribet) which is impossible because all semistable elliptic curves are modular (per Andrew Wiles)

Answer (score 2):

As rational powers indicate roots and as irrational roots exist, the statement should be *immediately* seen as obviously false. And $2^{\frac 12} = \sqrt 2$ should be an immediate and obvious counterexample.

Answer (score 1):

The statement is false.

**Counterexample:**

Let $x=5\;\text{and let }y=\frac12$, so $x$ and $y$ are both rational.

Then $x^y=5^{(1/2)}=\sqrt5$, which is irrational.

This works for any $x$ which is not a perfect square.

Answer (score 0):

Assume $2^{\frac{1}{TREE(3)}}$ is rational.

Then there are coprime integers $z_1$ and $z_2$ such that

$$\frac{z_1}{z_2}=2^{\frac{1}{TREE(3)}} $$

Raise both sides to the $TREE(3)$th power.

$$\frac{{z_1}^{TREE(3)}}{{z_2}^{TREE(3)}}=2$$

Multiply by ${z_2}^{TREE(3)}$

$${z_1}^{TREE(3)}=2{z_2}^{TREE(3)}={z_2}^{TREE(3)}+{z_2}^{TREE(3)}$$

So we have a perfect ($TREE(3)$)th power that can be expressed as a sum of two perfect ($TREE(3)$)th powers.

But this contradicts Fermat's Last Theorem, as proven by Andrew Wiles in 1995, because:

if this was true, there would be an immodular, semistable elliptic curve, proven by Ken Ribet in 1986,

contradicting the proof by Wiles that all semistable elliptic curves as modular.

So there is an irrational $x^y$ for rational$x$ and rational $y$